# At what depth are spider cave biomes located in Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I have spent more than a dozen hours exploring my large world in Terraria (version 1.4.2.2 / Classic difficulty) and still haven't found a spider cavern so as to rescue the Stylist NPC. Knowing what depth or layer (underground or cavern) the spider cavern biome spawns in would help me narrow my search.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Vertically-speaking, they can be found anywhere in the underground and cavern levels (between 0ft and ~3100ft in a large map, if you have a Depth Meter). When you start to see Ash Blocks, you've gone too far down.

And they can be found beneath any biome EXCEPT the Jungle. They're slightly more rare underneath the Snow Biome, so you'll have the best luck in the regular stone-and-dirt underground/cavern.

<sub>Source, [Gamefaqs](https://gamefaqs.gamespot.com/pc/630609-terraria/answers/371513-where-can-i-find-spider-web).</sub>

---

Note: The [Dangersense Potion](https://terraria.fandom.com/wiki/Dangersense_Potion) can be useful in locating Spider Caves, because the Cobwebs inside sparkle in a unique pattern.

Comment: Upvoted. The comment about dangersense potion allowed me to locate a hidden spider cave biome almost immediately. My new problem is that the stylist NPC is still not showing up there. If this continues I may submit a new question about why this is.

Comment: @MarkRipley glad to help